# Center div inside a div

Tags: html, css

I searched a lot but I didn't find any solution.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
   <div class="icon-container">
      <div class="icon">
          <h1>10C</h1>
      </div>                    
   </div>
     <h2>text</h2>
</div>
```

..and here css:

```
.icon-container{
    height:160px; 
    width:160px;    
    display:inline-block;
}

.icon{
    background: url(image/template.png);
    height:140px; 
    width:140px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.icon h1{
    color: white;
}
```

The class col-lg-4 come from bootsrap.
Well, I want to center icon class inside icon-container, and also icon h1 inside icon.
I hope you understand.

With the code above the div icon doesn't center in div icon-containter. It's important that I don't modify the width and the height of the two divs.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works :)

```css
.icon-container{
    height:160px; 
    width:160px;    
    display:inline-block;
  
    border:3px solid black;
     position:relative;
}

.icon{
    background: url(image/template.png);
    height:140px; 
    width:140px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
     vertical-align: middle;
  
  
    border:2px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:8px;
    
   
}

.icon h1{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
   <div class="icon-container">
      <div class="icon">
          <h1><br />Text1</h1>
      </div>                    
   </div>
     <h2>Text2</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice but if I want to make a javascript animation? For example expand the circle from 140px to 160px like the icon-container when I click it.

Comment: You can use scale() in css for that. Anyways,welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
.icon-container{
    height:160px; 
    width:160px;    
    display:inline-block;
}

.icon{
    background: url(image/template.png);
    height:140px; 
    width:140px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.icon h1{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also please, don't use `color: white`, a quick Google will show you certain browsers may have certain definitions for colors, for example `blue` may look different in certain browsers. For `white` that's not the case but still.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in bootstrap:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
   <div class="icon-container">
      <div class="icon center">
          <h1>10C</h1>
      </div>                    
   </div>
     <h2>text</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You only need to add a "Margin: auto;" the css of the classe icon and if it does not work I recommend using "identifiers (id)" that Bootstrap has saved many classes that can confuse the system. .icon{margin: auto;}

Comment: He's using `display: inline-block`, that won't work accordingly.l

Answer (score -3):

`margin: 0 auto` - simply use the `margin:0 auto;` This will work for centering a lot of things! Good luck.

Comment: Or we could stop encouraging people from using outdated methods just because they are a quick fix and a mask for our ignorance.

Comment: Also, to center your H1 tag, just simply add: text-align:center; to the element. But <center> tags should center everything.

Comment: As @ShowTime said, it's better to encourage using modern-standard methods and not outdated ones. This will make OP's code fail validation through w3c. The `margin: 0 auto` is the correct way to go

Comment: @ChenAsraf - Hey guys, Yeah I understand. But it's just an option! I use the margin method personally, which is why I wrote it down!

Comment: Running your method through a JSFiddle will quickly show it doesn't work. Notice he's using `display: inline-block`

Comment: @ShowTime No worries, I should've looked over more carefully! But your right, he shouldn't use the <center> tags.

Comment: @James still your answer is not going to help the OP, you're saying it will center lots of things, not the things in his case, which makes your answer pointless.